# Can you execute more than one batch file in the same PSExec command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, psexec

I am using `PSExec` to execute a batch file on a remote machine.  I am using the command to execute one batch file:

```
c:\Sysinternals\PsExec.exe \\SERVER -u USER -p PASSWORD D:\somefile.bat
```

But let's say I wanted to execute two batch files.  The first batch file does some sort of authentication to a database and it gets cached.  But after the user logs out, the token is removed.

If I did two different PSExec commands I assume that it will run in two different sessions.

Is there a way I could nest two different batch files into the same `PSExec` command ?

Comment: you can chain the commands using `&` something like `psexec \\SERVER -u USER -p PASSWORD -e cmd /c (batch1 ^& batch2)` I cannot test this as I do not have `psexec`, but remember doing it like this back in the day.

Comment: Perhaps `call`ing at least the first of them would be preferable, @Gerhard

Comment: You may put in the last line of the first file, the name of the second one. In this way the execution _continues_ from the first file to the second...